# Get Path from array in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I wonder is there possibility to get path from array outside views (in my case in model) like in link_to method - `link_to 'User', [:admin, @user]` .

For example I want to store `admin_artist_path` (unfortunately real problem is more complex because I can't predict what path will be )

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  before_save :store_path!

  private

    def store_path!
      self.url = [:namespace, :artist].do_some_magick
    end

  end
```

ps. I know about url_for() method but for some reasons it must be path.

Thanks for help!

Comment: _unfortunately real problem is more complex because I can't predict what path will be_ --- why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to include both of these classes

```
include ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

before_save :store_path!

private

def store_path!
  self.url = polymorphic_path([:namespace, :artist])
end
```

Comment: Thanks, just like I wanted :)
I'll be happy if you can explain what does `include ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes` stand for? It seems to work with just `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`